# Relationship between ord($a$) and ord($a^k$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in group $G$.

Prove that if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $a^m$ has order $n$. (Hint: If $a^{mk}=e$, use the theorem: $a^t=e$ iff $t$ is a multiple of $n$, i.e., $t=nq$, and explain why $n$ must be a factor of $k$.)

---

So far I have:

Let ord($a$)=$n$ and let gcd($m,n$)$=1$, $m \in \Bbb Z$.
Suppose $a^{mk}=e$. Then $a^{mk}=a^n.$ So $mk=n$. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $n \nmid m$. So $n$ must divide $k$, i.e., $k=nq$, for some $q \in \Bbb Z$.

---

I'm quite confused as to how to proceed. I know I need to show that $(a^m)^n=e$, but I don't know how. Any direction at all will be appreciated!

I also have to prove it the other way, making this an if and only if statement!

EDIT: The group $G$ is not necessarily abelian, meaning it is not commutative.

Comment: $(a^m)^n = (a^n)^m$

Comment: Does that still work if G is not commutative?

Comment: The has to do with the associative property, not commutative, e.g. $(aa)(aa)(aa) = (aaa)(aaa)$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how do I proceed from what I have so far? Or does what I have not work?

Comment: Is it enough to say that since gcd(m,n)=1, then n divides k, so n must be the order?

Comment: My original comment only shows why $(a^m)^n=e$. You still need to argue that the order of $a^m$ is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

So from the Theorem in the hint, we know that ord$(a^k)$ | ord$(a)$. Hence ord$(a^m)$ | $n$. Let $x= \text{ord}(a^m).$ So $(a^m)^x=a^{mx}=e.$ Thus $n$ | $mx$. But gcd$(m,n)$=$1$. So $n$ | $x$, i.e., $n$ | ord$(a^m)$. Therefore ord$(a^m)=n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then the smallest positive integer $x$ satisfying $xm\equiv 0 \mod n$ is $x=n$.

Proof: if $xm=\alpha n$ for some integer $\alpha$, because $n$ and $m$ share no prime factors,  the prime factorisation of the left hand side will only include all the primes in the prime factorisation of $n$ if $x|n$ (and the smallest $x$ satisfying this is $x=n$).

Thus the lowest $x$ for which $(a^{m})^x=e$ is the lowest $x$ for which $mx=xm\equiv 0 \mod n$ (i.e. $x=n$).

Comment: I don't understand... I am lost with $xm=an$.